# uwsgi subprocess create a new process,the socket close wait

Tags: python, uwsgi, bottle

I use bottle and uwsgi.

uwsgi config:

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket = :8087
processes = 4
workers=4
master = true
file=app.py
```

app.py:

```
import bottle
import os

application = bottle.app()

@bottle.route('/test')
def test():
    os.system('./restart_ssdb.sh')

if __name__=='__main__':
    bottle.run()
```

restart_ssdb.sh(just restart a service and do not care about what the service is):

```
./ssdb-server -d ssdb.conf -s restart
```

Then I start the uwsgi and it works well.

[image]

Then I access url:127.0.0.1/test

[image]

The image shows that one of uwsgi processes becomes ssdb server.

Then I stop uwsgi:

[image]

The port 8087 belongs to ssdb. It causes uwsgi server to be unable to restart because the port is used.

1. What causes the problem in Figure 2 to appear?
2. I just want to execute shell(restart ssdb server), But it must be
   guaranteed not to affect the uwsgi server, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html

I solve it when i set the

> close-on-exec

option to my uwsgi setting